# Immediately after logging in, system freezes with dialog

Tags: login

I installed 18.04 recently and now when I log in, immediately after supplying the password, the screen blanks and a dialog pops up that says "Are you sure you want to proceed?" (attached a pict).  the only way I have found to get around this is to plug a wired mouse into the system and try to 'catch' it before it becomes responsive.  When I get to the button and click "OK" everything proceeds as expected and operates correctly.

What is this dialog and how to "FIX" it so it isn't popping up.[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2iML.jpg)

Comment: What happens if you press Escape instead?

Comment: It had no effect.  I went through and disabled all the apps in the startup and I commented out all the drives I was mounting in fstab also, but no effect either. At this point, I am just reinstalling again to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Grab the latest version off the net. Bug fixes can occur at any time.